# Intranet Messaging

Tags: software-rec, instant-messaging, intranet

Are there any, **preferably free** (as this is for a Not for Profit Organization) software for Intranet Messaging? If the software is serverless, it would be better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use [Spark](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/spark/index.jsp) at my work.

From the website:

> Spark is an Open Source, cross-platform IM client optimized for businesses and organizations. It features built-in support for group chat, telephony integration, and strong security. It also offers a great end-user experience with features like in-line spell checking, group chat room bookmarks, and tabbed conversations.
>   Combined with the Openfire server, Spark is the easiest and best alternative to using un-secure public IM networks.

Answer (score 6):

[Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/) supports the Bonjour chat protocol, which is serverless.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Pichat](http://www.pichat.net/)

From the [FAQ notes](http://www.pichat.net/documentation/pichat_faq),

> Pichat is an own chat system. There are a couple of chat command that are similar to IRC (Inter Relay Chat), but under the hood runs an own protocol and a peer-to-peer chat system that does not rely on a centralised server. Basically you can run an independent chat service and adjust it to your own needs.
>
> After downloading and starting the Pichat software you already have a running LAN messenger, chat server and web server. To make the chat accessible from the Internet you need to configure your firewall, router or cable modem correspondingly. Pichat uses the following ports: 9009/TCP and 80/TCP (in default settings).

You might also find this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911263/what-is-a-good-implementation-of-a-peer-to-peer-chat-program-with-a-server-for-as) interesting.

Answer (score 1):

We use [RealPopup](http://www.matro.it/site/show/english/realpopup.aspx), which is a replacement of the old Winpopup windows messaging. It's simple, serverless and free. Downside is that for some reason it crashes on some computers and AFAIK is not developed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows,try [Net Send](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_send.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: I think Net Send doesn't work on Windows XP SP2 and onwards, or does it?

Comment: The messenger services is disabled by default, but can be started from services.msc. In Vista and above, the service does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

At our small business we use [BigAnt](http://www.bigantsoft.com/). It still has a server, but that is fairly light and can be run on a normal machine.

Answer (score 0):

Netsend has disappeared under Windows 7 so you might have to use `msg.exe` or `dmessage` ...