# LAN messenger for Windows with features like Google Talk

Tags: software-rec, instant-messaging, chat, google-talk

Currently we are using Google Talk as messenger at our work place. Now we are supposed to replace it with some LAN based messenger. It should have at least following features chatting ( if logs are stored some where than it is good ), File sharing. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could run [openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/)

- it uses jabber (the same protocol as gtalk) so your learning curve is minimal - its free, with the option of support (with some paid plugins) and fairly simple to set up and run. management is through a web interface. Its free and open source as well, and runs on windows or linux

Comment: Running your own Jabber server allows for open standards-based chat serving. Plus this would allow you to log chats if need be.

Comment: I implemented Openfire years ago and have been VERY pleased ever since.

Comment: checked it thoroughly now.. and without any hesitation its one of the best. Recommended. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was looking for a solution like this for a long time. Openfire + Spark is an excellent option for business usage.

Answer (score 2):

Pidgen [ZeroConf](http://ubuntu.online02.com/node/19) using the Bonjour protocol
no server to setup, the users can see each other as they come online via brodcast
Link explain installation on Windows/Linux/Mac

Using it for the better half of the year, works_as_expected = true;

Update:
 you **don't** have to  : "Use the *SAME* 'Hostname' for ALL clients" as the guid explains

Comment: Pidgin is free, open-source and pretty easy to setup for your users. Not to mention that the ZeroConf "Bonjour" is a standard so your users could pick a different client (Adium, iChat for Mac)

Comment: I tested it today but some how after working for few minutes when I tried file transfer it stopped working .. Tried hard to figure it out but was not able to got it right.

Comment: maybe there are some broadcast limits, or hardware frirewall in  your network. Our company uses it on Kubuntu

Answer (score 2):

I can only recommend [**LANTalk.NET**](http://www.lantalk.net/lantalk-net/), it is not free but shareware, you can try before you buy.

[image]

Key Features

```
* File transfers replace e-mail attachments
* Broadcast Messaging for instant broadcasting
* Terminal Server Support
* Serverless operation with live contact list
* Paste images from clipboard
* Internal Scheduler
* HIPAA friendly instant messenger
* Active Directory support
* Offline delivery
* Graphical Emoticons and Embedded Images
* Configurable user interface
* Read-Only and Reply-Only modes to restrict social chatting
* Printing support
* Fast Replies
* Multilanguage support
* Conversation History
* Automatic Check for Updates
* Message priority
```

Comment: Thanks Molly but I am looking for free options first. Thanks again for the information.

Comment: perfectly understandable :)

Answer (score 1):

[IP Messenger](http://www.ipmsg.org/index.html.en)

Comment: @Sathya : I have tested it, but it is very annoying to have a  popup on the middle of screen but still I will give it full marks for being light weight and easy to use. File transfer is very good.

Comment: yeah, it is a very usefull program. We use it in our office too..

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at answers to my related question:

[[Intranet Messaging](https://superuser.com/questions/31807/intranet-messaging][1])

Comment: Thanks mate.. cant vote up.. but +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Borgchat](http://borgchat.softnews.ro/) mostly because of its Multilanguage support and easy access to other Computers shared folders.