# Lan secure chat choice

Tags: software-rec, lan, instant-messaging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simple Local Network Chat Program](https://superuser.com/questions/37751/simple-local-network-chat-program)

I'm looking for a chat application to use in a small company LAN, we are looking for a software that offers secure (encrypted) text communication (voice and video are not a must, but is welcome as well) able to run in different platforms (mainly windows and mac) and free (or Open source)

I have been looking on the internet and I found some nice apps, but all of them fall in some features. For example this one http://messenger.softros.com/ looks very nice, but is only for windows.

This one looks nice too http://lan-chat.srimax.com/ but is not free.

Do you know any suitable application that fits my needs?

Answer (score 1):

[Jabber](http://www.jabber.org/) supports encryption and have many clients. It's in use in some universities for example and you should find OpenSources implementations.

Answer (score 0):

http://silcnet.org/support/faq/client/

I don't think it does voice or video but it is secure Irc-like chat. Edit: correction. Yes it does.