# Lan Messenger with voice and screensharing

Tags: windows, voice, screen-sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LAN messenger for Windows with features like Google Talk](https://superuser.com/questions/37654/lan-messenger-for-windows-with-features-like-google-talk)

Need a LAN Messenger for a home network with

- Voice
- Text Messages
- Screen Sharing capabilities

It could be a paid software, please advise *(ideally would like to avoid those that need a server to be installed)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at yuuguu?  They may have the soultion that you are looking for.

Comment: but yuuguu doesn't seem like its a lan messenger, its meant for enterprise uses which connect over vpn or the internet, i'm specifically looking for a lan based messenger which will be way faster than connecting to the internet to do the same. I already have skype which does all this for free.